# Apache to listen on certain port

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, centos, alias, httpd.conf

I am running a kolab server and trying to increase security by having the web-admin listen on a certain port.. I picked 8443. Here's my conf file:

```
Alias /kolab-webadmin /usr/share/kolab-webadmin/public_html/

<Directory "/usr/share/kolab-webadmin/public_html/">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        # NOTE: This needs to point to the base uri of your installation.
        RewriteBase /kolab-webadmin/

        # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
        RewriteRule ^api/(.*)\.(.*)$ api/index.php?service=$1&method=$2 [L,QSA]

    </IfModule>

    AddDefaultCharset   UTF-8
    php_value error_reporting      6135

    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All

    <ifModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </ifModule>
    <ifModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </ifModule>

</Directory>
```

I am not sure exactly how to make this work... I am also on centos 6.6

**EDIT:**

I only want this specific address to listen on port 8443...

so domain.com/something   will work on port 80

but domain.com/kolab-webadmin   works only on 8443

Comment: `Listen` directive is only valid in server config (not directory ). What you need to do is create new virtual host with new port!

Comment: @undone can you help with that? I tried editing in httpd.conf but I get:   [Wed Sep 02 18:42:29 2015] [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 8443, the first has precedence

Comment: Having the web-admin listen on a certain port will not increase security.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Listen 8443
NameVirtualHost yourdomain.com:8443
<VirtualHost yourdomain.com:8443>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@yourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot "yourDocumentRoot"
    ServerName yourdomain.com
    ServerAlias www.yourdomain.com
    Alias /kolab-webadmin /usr/share/kolab-webadmin/public_html/

    <Directory "/usr/share/kolab-webadmin/public_html/">
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine on
            # NOTE: This needs to point to the base uri of your installation.
            RewriteBase /kolab-webadmin/

            # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
            RewriteRule ^api/(.*)\.(.*)$ api/index.php?service=$1&method=$2 [L,QSA]

        </IfModule>

        AddDefaultCharset   UTF-8
        php_value error_reporting      6135

        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All

        <ifModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all granted
        </ifModule>
        <ifModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from All
        </ifModule>

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:8443

Comment: You need to terminate the process which is using that port or choose another port!

Comment: Okay now that worked.. but if i type in domain.com:8447    - it doesn't go straight to the kolab-webadmin   sorry i am not an apache genius :(